# Spring 4 mvc HTTP 404 rsource not found

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat8

I am new in Spring and i try a simple mvc example with java configuration.
I receive an HTT 404 error when requesting my home page.

Spring 4, Tomcat 8.5, Eclipse
Here comes my code

pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>SpringProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>SpringProject</name>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.3.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupd>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

DispacherServlet.java

```
package arnaud.spring.configuration;

public class DispatcherServletForMVC extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    protected String[] getServletMappings(){
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        System.out.println("dans initialisation root");
        return null;        
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        System.out.println("dans initialisation servlet");
        return new Class<?>[] {WebConfig.class};
    }
}
```

WebConfig class

```
package arnaud.spring.configuration;
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="arnaud.spring")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    //define the view resolver
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        System.out.println("view resolver");
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver= new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer){
        configurer.enable();
        System.out.println("default handling");
    }
}
```

Now my controller...

```
package arnaud.spring.controllers;
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(){
        System.out.println("dans controller");
        return "HomePage";
    }
}
```

My HomePage.jsp located in WEB-INF/views

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix ="c" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Home Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a ref="<c:url value="/listinvoice"/>">list invoice</a>
        <a ref="<c:url value="/listinvoice/register"/>">register</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Finally what i can see in the Eclipse console

> mars 03, 2017 4:05:48 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
>           AVERTISSEMENT: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context}
>          Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringMVCProject' did not find a matching property.
>            mars 03, 2017 4:05:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>           INFOS: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.6
>           mars 03, 2017 4:05:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>          INFOS: Server built:          Oct 6 2016 20:15:31 UTC
>          mars 03, 2017 4:05:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>         INFOS: Server number:         8.5.6.0
>         mars 03, 2017 4:05:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>         INFOS: OS Name:               Windows 10
>         mars 03, 2017 4:05:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>         INFOS: OS Version:            10.0
>          mars 03, 2017 4:05:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>         INFOS: Architecture:          amd64
>         mars 03, 2017 4:05:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>        INFOS: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111
>        mars 03, 2017 4:05:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>         INFOS: JVM Version:           1.8.0_111-b14
>         mars 03, 2017 4:05:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>        INFOS: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
>        mars 03, 2017 4:05:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>        mars 03, 2017 4:05:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>        INFOS: 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
>        dans initialisation root
>        dans initialisation servlet
>        mars 03, 2017 4:05:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>        INFOS: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
>        mars 03, 2017 4:05:51 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
>        INFOS: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
>        mars 03, 2017 4:05:51 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
>       INFOS: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet':
>       startup date [Fri Mar 03 16:05:51 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>       mars 03, 2017 4:05:51 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext loadBeanDefinitions
>       INFOS: Registering annotated classes: [class arnaud.spring.configuration.WebConfig]
>        mars 03, 2017 4:05:52 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
>       INFOS: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Mar 03 16:05:51 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>       mars 03, 2017 4:05:52 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping register
>        INFOS: Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String arnaud.spring.controllers.HomeController.home()
>        default handling
>        mars 03, 2017 4:05:52 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
>       INFOS: Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler]
>       view resolver
>       mars 03, 2017 4:05:53 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
>       INFOS: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 2087 ms
>       mars 03, 2017 4:05:55 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
>       INFOS: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
>       mars 03, 2017 4:05:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
>       INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8085]
>       mars 03, 2017 4:05:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
>       INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8008]
>       mars 03, 2017 4:05:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>       INFOS: Server startup in 9320 ms

I call the page with the following url, my tomcat in Eclipe in on port 8085

http://localhost:8085/SpringMVCProject/
or
http://localhost:8085/SpringMVCProject

with same result:HTTP 404

Thanks very much for helping me solving this issue.

Comment: Since you're new, do yourself a favor and use [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/), you'll save a lot of time not having to configure everything yourself.

Comment: Moreover, spring-boot-web-starter is a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

You need to Map your Dispatcher Servlet in the web.xml and your web config class this is using the Default dispatcher you need to replace with yours

```
       <servlet>
<servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
  <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>arnaud.spring.configuration.WebConfig</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Like this

```
 <servlet>
<servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
        arnaud.spring.configuration.DispatcherServletForMVC
</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
  <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>arnaud.spring.configuration.WebConfig</param-value>
</init-param>
```